# WiX: Close app before install and run automatically only if it was running

Tags: wix

I have a slightly different need that most of the other posts I've found on a search...

I need my installer to check if the application is currently running on a re-install (or upgrade), shut it down but remember that it was running, and then after the installation, start the application only if it had been running at the start.

Is there not a set of standard custom actions that can be used to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Made CA for detection the application and set some property in this CA (i.e. APPISRUN; MsiSetProperty(hInstall, "APPISRUN","1"); ), execute this CA before removing existing products. Run the application after intsallation, if APPISRUN == 1. About CA - http://bonemanblog.blogspot.in/2005/10/custom-action-tutorial-part-i-custom.html